# How can i add a number to a file name in php

Tags: php, regex, file

Goodevening to everyone, how can i add a number to a file name in php.
Let me explain; I want to save a file using a dropzone but i want to rename the file if it exist in the folder.
I've written down this code but the regex doesn't work and also if it's possible to insert the number before the extension of the file like google chrome does.

```
if(file_exists($target_file)){
    if(preg_match_all($target_file, "'('[0-9]{1,}')'")==false){
        $target_file= $target_path."(1)".$name;
    }else{
        $pos=preg_match_all($target_file, "'('[0-9]{1,}')'");
        $pos=$pos++;
        $pos1=strpos($pos, $target_file, ")");
        $pos1=$pos1-$pos;
        $num=substr($target_file, $pos, $pos1);
        $num = (int)$num;
        $num =$num++;
        $sostituisci="(".$num.")";
        $target_file=preg_replace("'('[0-9]{1,}')'", $sostituisci, $target_file);
    }
}
```

$name is the name of the file i want to save with the extension
the first $target_file of the code contain the full path + the name of the file

$target_file is a sting like /dropzone/upload/filename.txt and $name is a string like filename.txt. If the $targetfile exist i would to rename the $name like filename(1).txt or filename(2).txt and so on

also other solutions are accepted like a js library.

Comment: Please show an example of `$target_file` and `$name`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to this set of code here.

```
if(preg_match_all($target_file, "'('[0-9]{1,}')'")==false){
    $target_file= $target_path."(1)".$name;
}
```

`insert the number before the extension of the file`

**EDIT:** *Use explode() and re-format the ext.*

EXAMPLE:

```
$target_path = "/assets/imgages/";
$name = 'img.jpg';
$name = explode('.', $name);
$format = $name[0].'(1).'.$name[1];
$path = $target_path.$format;
```

Will produce the following string:

```
/assets/img/notes(1).txt
```

Accept multiple dots in string.

```
$filename = 'company.jobtitle.field.text';  

function formatDuplicateExtension($filename){
    $stmt = NULL;
    $format = explode('.', $filename);
    $i = 0;
    foreach($format as $key => $value){     
        if($value === end($format)){
            $stmt .= '(1).'.$format[$i];
        }elseif($key === count($format)-2){
            $stmt .= $format[$i];
        }else{
            $stmt .= $format[$i].'.';
        }
    $i++;     
    }
return $stmt;
}

echo formatDuplicateExtension($filename);
```

`$filename = 'company.jobtitle.field.text';`

**OUTPUTS:** //-->`/assets/imgages/company.jobtitle.field(1).text`

`$name = 'trees.vac2012.img.jpg';`

**OUTPUTS:** //--> `/assets/imgages/trees.vac2012.img(1).jpg`

Comment: maybe i've not explained myself correctly now $name contain a string like filename.txt i need to change it in a string like filename(1).txt or filename(2).txt if filename(1).txt exist and so on

Comment: my problem isn't in change the name i have to find the latest occurency of a string like ".ext" and insert a string before like (1) if it not exist or (2) (3) (4) and so on if the file exist

Comment: if the file contain a dot in the name like file.name.txt?
and if the file exist how can i find the file named filename(1).txt?

Comment: You could check to see how many items are in the array and then code accordingly. 'if(count($name) = 2){ //explode and format using iterator } or a for() loop that checks if <= to count, then iterates.

Comment: ok i will try  thanks and for find the (number) occurency? i cannot use explode()...

Comment: Okay, check out additional code for example that will accept multiple dots regardless of amount. You will also need to implement a check to see how many files have how many extensions for duplicates as well.

Comment: how can i check if the file exist? that was my first problem how can i find an occurency like (1) , (2) or in general (number) and be sure that is the latest one before the extension?

Comment: `scandir()`... it returns an array of files and directories from the directory you define.

Comment: i can use also file_exists() my problem was to find the pattern in the name of the file but seems i've figured out there is a function preg_match_all() that can be used with regex

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution idk if it's the best one because regex searches and substitutions are involved a lot of times and it seems to be they're resources consuming functions.

```
//this function insert the $number in the name of the file before .extension
function InsertBeforeExtension($filename,$number){
    $stmt = NULL;
    $format = explode('.', $filename);
    $i = 0;
    foreach($format as $key => $value){     
        if($value === end($format)){
            $stmt .= '('.$number.').'.$format[$i];
        }elseif($key === count($format)-2){
            $stmt .= $format[$i];
        }else{
            $stmt .= $format[$i].'.';
        }
    $i++;     
    }
return $stmt;
}

//this function check if there's a string like (number).ext in the name
//if yes increment the (number) in the string that become (number++).ext
//if no insert (1) before .ext
function insertnumber($string){
    $matches=array();
    $re = '/[(][0-9]+[)]\.[a-zA-Z]+/m';
    preg_match_all($re, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
    if($matches[0][0]){
        //if (number).ext is present
        $re = '/[(][0-9]+[)]/m';
        $str = $matches[0][0];
        //select the (number) only
        preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
        //remove parethesis
        $str=substr($matches[0][0],1,-1);
        //cast sting to an int for add a number
        $int = (int)$str;
        $int++;
        //replace the last (number) match in the name of the file with (number++)
        $re = '/(.*)[(][0-9]+[)]/m';
        $subst = '${1}('.$int.')';
        $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $string);
    }else{
        //if (number).ext is not present insert (1) before .ext
        $result=InsertBeforeExtension($string,1);
    }
    return $result;
};

$target_file = $target_path.$name;
//If the file exist repeat to find the number of file that doesn't exist
        if( file_exists( $target_file )) {
            while(file_exists( $target_file )){
                $name=insertnumber($name);
                $target_file = $target_path.$name;
            }
        }
```

The only problem is that if you have uploaded a file named like file(3).txt and you upload another file with the same name this function rename it in file(4).txt and not in file(3)(1).txt but for my scope this is not important

I've commented the code trying to be the most clear possible this solution seems to work well but i've not calculate the performance.